# Need $save() on the other page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular. I have a resource object called $scope.recruitmentProject and this object has $save() method.

I need to pass this object to another page so I did it like this-

```
    $state.go('company.editRecruitmentProject', {'project': angular.toJson(recruitmentProject)});
```

on the other page I get this object like this-

```
    $scope.project = angular.fromJson( decodeURIComponent( $stateParams.project ) );
```

now $scope.project don't have the $save() method.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JSON can only serialize data, not functions. So in this case, I would suggest you to put the `project` object into a separated service, so both controller can access it.

```
// In ProjectService.js
.service('ProjectService', function() {
  // Put project related logic here
}
```

Then inject `ProjectService` into your controller and use it.

Comment: if i put it into a service I think it will call the server for the data  2 times, that's why i'm passing the from one page to another page to reduce the server hits. Any other idea ??

Comment: You can keep a cache in the service.